# AngularJS Error: [$controller:ctrlreg] Controller is not registered

Tags: ruby-on-rails, angularjs

StackOverflow Peeps,

I'm having a bit of an issue with the error referenced in the title. I've scoured AngularJS documentation, previously written code, and existing StackOverflow question/answers, all to no avail. To start, here is a previously written Angular controller that works correctly:

[Correct, functioning controller](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xGGZb.png)

[image]

And here is the malfunctioning controller:

[Malfunctioning controller](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d2hkn.png)

[image]

What is particularly frustrating is that I quite literally copied my code from the functioning Angular controller ("focus_groups_ctrl") into my new controller ("agencies_ctrl"), and simply updated the variable/argument names to reflect this. What am I missing here? The JSON data being rendered in api/v1/agencies is working correctly, and my HTML page is being correctly "wrapped" in ng-app and ng-controller attributes. Please let me know, and feel free to ask away! Thanks!

Here is the malfunctioning code:

```js
/* global angular */

(function() {
  "use strict";

  angular.module("app", ["ngAnimate"]).controller("agencies_Ctrl", function($scope, $http) {
    $scope.setup = function() {
      $http.get('/api/v1/agencies' + window.location.search).then(function(response) {
        $scope.agenciesOffset = 0;
        $scope.agenciesCount = 5;
        $scope.agencies = response.data;
        console.log($scope.agencies);
      });
    };
    var i = 5;
    $scope.nextLoad = function() {
      $scope.agenciesOffset = i;
      i += 5;
    };
  });
}());
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
```

And here is the functioning code:

```js
/* global angular */

(function() {
  "use strict";

  angular.module("app", ["ngAnimate"]).controller("focus_groups_Ctrl", function($scope, $http) {
    $scope.setup = function() {
      $http.get('/api/v1/focus-groups' + window.location.search).then(function(response) {
        $scope.focusGroupOffset = 0;
        $scope.focusGroupCount = 5;
        $scope.focusGroups = response.data;
        console.log($scope.focusGroups);
      });
    };
    var i = 5;
    $scope.nextLoad = function() {
      $scope.focusGroupOffset = i;
      i += 5;
    };
  });
}());
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: When asking a question about a problem caused by your code, you will get much better answers if you provide code people can use to reproduce the problem. Images of the code are unusable.

Comment: See [AngularJS Error Reference - ctrlreg](https://docs.angularjs.org/error/$controller/ctrlreg)

Comment: @georgeawg Thanks for the heads up! I've included code snippets of the two files

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An unknown controller error can also be caused by accidentally redefining a module using the `angular.module` API, as shown in the following example.

```
angular.module("app", ["ngAnimate"]).controller("agencies_Ctrl", fn1); 

angular.module("app", ["ngAnimate"]).controller("focus_groups_Ctrl", fn2);
```

To fix this problem, make sure you only define each module with the `angular.module(name, [requires])` syntax once across your entire project. Retrieve it for subsequent use with `angular.module(name)`. The fixed example is shown below.

```
angular.module("app", ["ngAnimate"]);

angular.module("app").controller("agencies_Ctrl", fn1); 

angular.module("app").controller("focus_groups_Ctrl", fn2);
```

Comment: Excellent, this is a perfect answer that fixed the problem. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Cannot believe that I am the first one vote this great answer up!